# PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb vs PixelFormat.Format64bppArgb

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap

I am developing an application using WPF, WPF bitmaps are PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb  by default. Is there any advantage/pitfalls using PixelFormat.Format64bppArgb as the pixel format. Which should I prefer? I have to display 8bit/16bit/32bit images. Should I use Format32bppArgb  /Format64bppArgb ?

Please point out some leads, Thanks in advance.

Comment: First pitfall would be using a Winforms enum in a WPF app.  Second pitfall would be finding a codec that can store 64bpp images.  Third one would be actually seeing any difference, LCD monitors are not nearly good enough.

Comment: HansPassant Hey, thanks for the quick comment.